MAUI Anroid - Build failed with jetbrains rider
I migrated an MAUI Net 8 project from the Xamarin project. when building the application with MAUI Android, it failed with the following exceptions,
Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266, 5): [NETSDK1004] Assets file '/Users/mark050/Documents/VA-DEV/SKM-Test/SKM_MOBILE/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
I noticed it also built the iOS platform code.
How to resolve this issue

the error message tells you exactly how to fix this problem: "Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file."

This indicates that the required NuGet packages are missing or need to be restored.

Run dotnet restore to fix missing packages.
Make sure you're building for Android, not iOS.
Clean the project and rebuild it to remove old errors.

